# Is it possible to have local file links on Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, stack-overflow-for-teams

On a Stack Overflow for Teams question I was trying to provide a file hyperlink, and it looks like file links are disabled in Stack Overflow, probably for security reasons, but for Stack Overflow for Teams it would often make sense to have links to a file or folder on our local servers. Is there a way to enable file links just for Stack Overflow for Teams?

Comment: If you really want this, you have to convince your team to stop using Google Chrome, or add an extension to everyone's installation (this comes with its security risks), as Google Chrome by default does not allow file links

Comment: [meta-tag:status-reproduced] @Ferrybig, nope SE is filtering them out. Try it out. Both the Markdown and the HTML version are converted to raw text.

Comment: @MEE even if SE wasn't filtering them out, they still wouldn't work, that is what I'm trying to say, you need more than SE allowing the feature

Comment: @Ferrybig yeah but how do you know that they (TJ's company) are using Chrome?

Comment: @MEE we are mostly using Chrome internally. I didn't realize that Chrome blocks file links by default, which makes sense, but we'll have to see if it would be reasonable to try to work around that.

Comment: @TJRockefeller: As a work-around, run a `SimpleHTTP` server to serve the static content of the filesystem in question...

Comment: @TJRockefeller - any particular reason not have the files delivered via HTTP / HTTPS? We are using an internal platform to upload the files that are linked in answers. It is not the best experience for the user, but it does not require any special security changes.

Comment: @Alexei I think you answered your own question. Obviously there are other ways of hosting files that would be accessible as a link, but it would be extremely convenient if we could link to an existing file share network that is set up for local access, and not web access.